# How to add arrays where I'll input the items and the data will show, not static array I want it dynamic

Tags: java, arrays

As you can see, I have arrays where I've already called the string, my professor instructed me to add the string by inputing the value and showing the results through scanner.

My professor wants that I'll input the Item ID, item description and the price, and compute it. I don't know how I should do the scanner for 3 arrays, would you guys please help how to do it thanks.

Please bear with me if I'm bad at asking questions this is my first time doing it on stackoverflow. Thanks!

P.S If you guys are getting confused with the codes I can provide the full codes, please comment as my original code is working with the original output.

Btw I know how to use scanner but I don't know how to use them in arrays and store it into 3 arrays.

```
               String[] id = new String[]{"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"};
               String[] item = new String[]{"Apple ", "Mango", "Orange", "Grapes", "Melon"};
               int[] price = new int[]{10, 12, 15, 20, 27};
               String itemEntered = "";
               boolean count_item = false;
               String itemQuery = "";
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component)null, "", "Shopping Cart", 1, icon);
               System.out.println("Item Id\t\tItem Description\t\tPrice");

               for(int ix = 0; ix < item.length; ++ix)
               {
                   System.out.println(id[ix] + "\t\t\t" + item[ix] + "\t\t\t\t" + price[ix]);
               }

               ArrayList itemID = new ArrayList();
               ArrayList itemName = new ArrayList();
               ArrayList quantity = new ArrayList();
               ArrayList total = new ArrayList();
```

Original output:

```
Item Id         Item Description        Price
item1           Apple            10
item2           Mango            12
item3           Orange           15
item4           Grapes           20
item5           Melon            27
```

Example expected output:

```
Item Id     Item Description        Price
qwre            Pants            100
asdf            Goodies          120
asdfg           Accessories      150
iqwe            Testing          200
eswry           Melon            270
```

As seen from above I should be the one to input the data through the scanner, not declared through the code.

Comment: What is the actual question? how to read user input from the console?

Comment: I want to know how to store the data in array through scanner, with 3 dimensional arrays, since there are 3 arrays which are id, item, and the price. 2 being a string and 1 being an integer.

Comment: Would you add the scanner code where you read the values? I assume, you're able to read and assign them to variables, just how to put them in arrays, that's the issue? But then you'll have the problem, that arrays can't be extended, once they're defined. You could re-create longer arrays at each input, but something like an ArrayList seems more appropriate honestly.

Comment: Man, these arrays are a pain in the ass @_@ Currently trying to store the data into arrays but somehow whenever I input the string it errors.

Comment: Oh guys, I've managed to store 1 array, I'll try to do to the other 2 arrays. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scanner](https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class) for 3 arrays can be done like this. 
1. create Scanner

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

2. get the table size from scanner

```
int tSize = scanner.nextInt();
```

3. pass the table size to your arrays. (i assume they should be same size)

```
    String[] id = new String[tSize];
    String[] item = new String[tSize];
    int[] price = new int[tSize];
```

4. loop thru the size to populate table.

```
for (int i=0; i<tSize; i++){
       System.out.println("Enter ID");
       id[i] = scanner.next();
       System.out.println("Enter Item");
       item[i] = scanner.next();
       System.out.println("Enter price");
       price[i] = scanner.nextInt();
   }
```

5. print your array content

```
 System.out.println("Item Id\t\tItem Description\t\tPrice");

    for(int ix = 0; ix < tSize; ++ix)
    {
        System.out.println(id[ix] + "\t\t\t" + item[ix] + "\t\t\t\t\t" + price[ix]);
    }
```

P.S if it is hard for you to puzzle up broken code here is a full code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Provide Table  size");
    int tSize = scanner.nextInt();
    String[] id = new String[tSize];
    String[] item = new String[tSize];
    int[] price = new int[tSize];

   for (int i=0; i<tSize; i++){
       System.out.println("Enter ID");
       id[i] = scanner.next();
       System.out.println("Enter Item");
       item[i] = scanner.next();
       System.out.println("Enter price");
       price[i] = scanner.nextInt();
   }

   scanner.close();

    System.out.println("Item Id\t\tItem Description\t\tPrice");

    for(int ix = 0; ix < tSize; ++ix)
    {
        System.out.println(id[ix] + "\t\t\t" + item[ix] + "\t\t\t\t\t" + price[ix]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also managed to finish mine but it is so long, this would be a good reference for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
static class Item {
 private int price;
 private String name, id;

 public Item (String id,String name,int price) {
this.id=id; this.name=name; this.price=price; }

public String getId(){return this.id;}
public String getName(){return this.name;}
public int getPrice(){return this.price;}
}

public class MainClass {
 public static void main(String args[]){

 Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
 List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();

 System.out.println("Enter amount of items:");

 int n = sc.nextInt();

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
 String [] in = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
 list.add(new Item(in[0],in[1],Integer.parseInt(in[2]))); }

System.out.println("Id \t Name \t Price");

for(Item s : list){
System.out.println(s.getId()+"\t"+s.getName()+"\t"+s.getPrice()); }}}
```

`Input

Enter amount of items:

2

Id1 apple 10

Id2 Milon 20

Output

Id     Name    Price

Id1   apple     10

Id2   Milon     20`

Comment: Thank you! Although I managed to figure it out though, my codes look messier than yours. :)